# highlight the word in gmail messages efficiently

Tags: javascript, data-structures, google-chrome-extension

Before stating my problem, I will describe the use case of the extension I am developing.

step 1 - The user logs in

step 2 - When the user opens up his/her gmail messages, the content script should run. In content script, what happens is it fetches the list of topics from api(the topics can be 1000+). But only 6 matched topics should be highlighted in the message that is opened currently. That means, I have to read each word in currently opened gmail message and if that word matches with the topics i get from api that word should get highlighted. if 6 topics are matched with the words in the gmail messages then the process is completed.

For this i tried in this way but the way i have done hangs my browser. I am seeking for efficient way of handling this situation.

Here it is

```
function fetchTopics() {
     const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3020/v2/topics`;
     const headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     headers.append(
        'Authorization',
        `Token: 77727c4080b111dc7ddd3c0330c1e7ea3b45e3213bdfbd27263c8d434b27c7c1`
     );
     fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers
     })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            topicData.map(datum => searchPage(data.name));
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
}

function searchPage(topic) {
    // console.log('topic', topic);
    var re = new RegExp(topic, 'g'); // example regex that the function will use for search
    var regs;

    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        function(node) {
            if ((regs = re.exec(node.textContent))) {
                if (!node.parentNode.classList.contains('highlighted_text')) {
                    var match = document.createElement('A');
                    match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
                    match.href = `https://app.production.navihq.com/CustomTopic/${
                        regs[0]
                    }`;

                    // add an attribute so we know this element is one we added
                    // Im using a class so you can target it with css easily
                    match.classList.add('highlighted_text');

                    var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
                    after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
                }
            }
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        },
        false
    );

    walker.nextNode();
}

// Run when the whole document loads
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    const emailDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('gb_Db');
    if (emailDOM) {
        window.chrome.storage.sync.set(
            { user_email: emailDOM[0].innerText },
            function() {}
        );
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', init);
  fetchTopics();
});

// Run on every hash change (when opening new mail)
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    fetchTopics();
});
```

Do anyone has better efficient solution for this ? My process has hunged my chrome several times.

Comment: It's possible your changes to the DOM cause an infinite loop in the walker. First collect the matching nodes (with `regs` of course) in an array, then process it.

Comment: I am really sorry i did not understand clearly. Can you please shed me some lights, please? just a sample or pseudocode.

Comment: Do you mean to say create an empty array let's say var topicsArr = []; and inside fetchTopics where i am doing `topicData.map(datum => searchPage(data.name));` change this to `topicData.map(datum => topicsArr.push(datum));`. Now inside searchPage create a for loop and check if the word matches or not?

Comment: @wOxxOm can you show me a sample, please? It would be a huge help.